# Error: picked up java_options: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Tags: java, android, cmd, ionic-framework

I get this error when doing anything in cmd involving Ionic and Android, e.g. Ionic build Android, or Ionic emulate Android etc... What does the error mean, is it important, and how do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "error" will happen if the variables JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS or _JAVA_OPTIONS are set. I don't believe it is or should be of much concern to anything. As long as the application runs fine I see no real issue. So no, it is not very important, and seeing as the application was still built (and is likely working normally), I don't see a reason to try and correct it.'

Additionally if you do have errors within the application where this is the root cause, [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/514807/) might be of some help.

Relevant/important post from the thread:

> A quick Google search indicates that this is output from the Java
>   virtual machine upon realizing that certain environment variables,
>   JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and JAVA_OPTIONS have been set.
>
> http://www.nbl.fi/~nbl97/java/tuning/troubles/
>
> These variables might be introduced in your Eclipse launch
>   configuration. More likely, they may have been set in your
>   workstation's environment by something you've recently installed.
>
> On Windows XP, you can access the environment variables by right
>   clicking on "My Computer", selecting "Properties", switch to the
>   "Advanced" tab and click "Environment Variables". In that window, you
>   should be able to see if the environment variable has been set up.
>
> Alternatively, you can open a command prompt and type "SET" to see
>   what environment variables have been set.

Comment: Ah yes, it seems when I was making my path I never noticed that I had a variable named JAVA_OPTIONS with those settings. Well, at least if there's an issue with it I know where it's sourced. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable is tucked in your environment settings, it is shown nowhere else. To remedy this,

1. Press the Windows key and the Pause/Break key simultaneously
2. A window should popup, click on "Advanced system settings"
3. Click on "Environment Variables"
4. Check System Variables.
5. Delete the _JAVA_OPTIONS entry.

Comment: When I delete the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable, it comes back the next time I restart my computer.